# Paired iPhone showing old playlists instead of iCloud playlists

Tags: iphone, itunes, mac, icloud, playlist

I recently made the switch to Apple Music and have enabled the iCloud Music Library feature. The setup has been smooth and without issues, I now have all of the playlists on my Mac synced over iCloud to my iPhone.

The issue is, all of the previous playlists from the last sync via cable (pre iCloud) are still showing up under 'on my device' section of the information pane for my iPhone when it is paired over wifi on iTunes.

Is there a way to have it update so that it displays the current playlists on the phone after having synced over iCloud?

Comment: When you say _recently_, how recently do you mean? I know of cases where it's taken days for everything to finish syncing via iCloud properly after initially switching to Apple Music and enabling the iCloud Music Library.

Comment: I enabled the iCloud Music Library feature exactly a week ago

Comment: Okay, well, assuming iTunes on your Mac has been connected then that really should have been long enough to upload content and sync things across (unless you have a massive library and slow internet).